# How do I setup Wireshark to run Lua's CLRPackage

Tags: .net, lua, wireshark, luainterface, clrpackage

I'm trying to setup [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) so that I can use the [LuaInterface](http://penlight.luaforge.net/packages/LuaInterface/#T5) to use some of the classes in the .NET framework.  I'm able to get it working running through the Lua command line, but when I try to `require "CLRPackage"` in the `init.lua` startup script, it doesnt appear to find the required files.  I get the following exception when starting Wireshark:

```
Lua: Error during loading:
 C:\Program Files\Wireshark\luascript.lua:25: module 'CLRPackage' not found:
    no field package.preload['CLRPackage']
    no file '.\CLRPackage.lua'
    no file 'C:\Program Files\Wireshark\lua\CLRPackage.lua'
    no file 'C:\Program Files\Wireshark\lua\CLRPackage\init.lua'
    no file 'C:\Program Files\Wireshark\CLRPackage.lua'
    no file 'C:\Program Files\Wireshark\CLRPackage\init.lua'
    no file 'C:\Program Files\Lua\5.1\lua\CLRPackage.luac'
    no file '.\CLRPackage.dll'
    no file '.\CLRPackage51.dll'
    no file 'C:\Program Files\Wireshark\CLRPackage.dll'
    no file 'C:\Program Files\Wireshark\CLRPackage51.dll'
    no file 'C:\Program Files\Wireshark\clibs\CLRPackage.dll'
    no file 'C:\Program Files\Wireshark\clibs\CLRPackage51.dll'
    no file 'C:\Program Files\Wireshark\loadall.dll'
    no file 'C:\Program Files\Wireshark\clibs\loadall.dll'
```

I've tried setting the `package.path` and `package.cpath` to match what is set at the command line, but that doesnt seem to help.

```
package.path = ";.\\?.lua;C:\\Program Files\\Lua\\5.1\\lua\\?.lua;C:\\Program Files\\Lua\\5.1\\lua\\?\\init.lua;C:\\Program Files\\Lua\\5.1\\?.lua;C:\\Program Files\\Lua\\5.1\\?\\init.lua;C:\\Program Files\\Lua\\5.1\\lua\\?.luac;C:\\Program Files\\Lua\\5.1\\lua\\?lua"

package.cpath = package.cpath .. ".\\?.dll;.\\?51.dll;C:\\Program Files\\Lua\\5.1\\?.dll;C:\\Program Files\\Lua\\5.1\\?51.dll;C:\\Program Files\\Lua\\5.1\\clibs\\?.dll;C:\\Program Files\\Lua\\5.1\\clibs\\?51.dll;C:\\Program Files\\Lua\\5.1\\loadall.dll;C:\\Program Files\\Lua\\5.1\\clibs\\loadall.dll;C:\\Program Files\\Lua\\5.1\\clibs\\luanet.dll"
```

When I do this, I get the following error:

```
Lua: Error during loading:
   error loading module 'luanet' from file 
   'C:\Program Files\Lua\5.1\clibs\luanet.dll':
   The spcecified module could not be found.
```

This is a strange error since the file definitely exists.

I've installed the Lua package for windows in `C:\Program Files\Lua\5.1`.

Has anyone been able to get this working?  Any help would be appreciated.

I'm using Wireshark 1.4.4 with Lua 5.1.4

Comment: Indicate what OS version you are using.

Comment: I downloaded luaforwindows from (http://code.google.com/p/luaforwindows/downloads/list).  It's version 5.1.4-45

Comment: Microsoft Windows XP Professional Version 2002 Service Pack 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received the help I needed over at the Wireshark site ([answer](https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/5868/how-do-i-setup-wireshark-to-run-luas-clrpackage))

**Your Wireshark is old.** The current stable release is [Wireshark 1.6.1](https://www.wireshark.org/download.html).

**Wireshark already includes Lua.** You don't need to install your own copy of Lua because Wireshark comes with its own Lua interpreter (and will only use its own). However, your Wireshark Lua scripts can still call the libraries installed by LuaForWindows.

**LuaInterface 1.5.3 is probably incompatible.** LuaForWindows v5.1.4-45 ships with LuaInterface 1.5.3, which might be incompatible with your Wireshark installation (exhibited by runtime error [R6034](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55984) upon loading luanet.dll). This was true for me with Wireshark 1.6.1 on Windows 7. You can get compatible binaries of LuaInterface 2.0.3 from this [ticket](https://code.google.com/archive/p/luaforwindows/issues/35).

**Instructions**

1) Copy the VS2005 SP1 Redistributables from LuaForWindows to Wireshark's program directory (or you can download the redist package from Microsoft...see ticket):

*From:*

- %PROGRAMFILES%\Lua\5.1\install\support\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.SP1\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.manifest
- %PROGRAMFILES%\Lua\5.1\install\support\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.SP1\msvcm80.dll
- %PROGRAMFILES%\Lua\5.1\install\support\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.SP1\msvcp80.dll
- %PROGRAMFILES%\Lua\5.1\install\support\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.SP1\msvcr80.dll

*To:*

- %PROGRAMFILES%\Wireshark\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.manifest
- %PROGRAMFILES%\Wireshark\msvcm80.dll
- %PROGRAMFILES%\Wireshark\msvcp80.dll
- %PROGRAMFILES%\Wireshark\msvcr80.dll
  2) Download LuaInterface 2.0.3 ZIP from this ticket, and copy the following from it:

*From:*

- ...\bin\Release\LuaInterface.dll
- ...\bin\Release\luanet.dll

*To:*

- %PROGRAMFILES%\Wireshark\clibs\LuaInterface.dll
- %PROGRAMFILES%\Wireshark\clibs\luanet.dll

*From:*

- ...\LuaInterface\lua\CLRForm.lua
- ...\LuaInterface\lua\CLRPackage.lua

*To:*

- %PROGRAMFILES%\Wireshark\lua\CLRForm.lua
- %PROGRAMFILES%\Wireshark\lua\CLRPackage.lua

3) Restart Wireshark/TShark if already running.

4) *OPTIONAL:* From Wireshark, open menu **Tools > Lua > Evaluate**. In the textbox that appears, enter some [sample code](https://web.archive.org/web/20120104044728/http://penlight.luaforge.net:80/packages/LuaInterface/#T7), and click **Evaluate**.

This should result in something like this:

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape backslashes when using "..." strings. You can avoid escaping if you use [[...]] strings.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Looks like SO removed the escape characters when I put it in quotes.  I changed it to code brackets.  I did have the backslashes escaped.  Any other ideas or does it look like its wrong from my update?